# Does the style attribute apply to all the divs having the same class or id?

Tags: html, css, themes

I have an already *developed website theme* and I want to change a few things in it.

What I want to change is how some blocks appear in a particular page. But the `div` I want to change shares its class with other `div`'s across the site (and on the same page as well).

**First** I changed the `background-color` of the `div` in the `CSS` file in its `class`. But as expected, the background color of the `div`'s on many other web pages which shared the `class` also changed.

**Then** I proceeded to change the inline `background-color` of the div like this:

```
<div id= "content" class="row" style="background-color:pink;" > ... </div>
```

I thought this background color would only be reflected in the div with the inline-style, but surprisingly it also changed the other `div`'s in the home page.

So what should I conclude from this?

**Does this mean that the style attribute is somehow magically being given to all the div's having row as a class or content as an id?**

**Or does it mean the homepage is also using this layout file instead of the file ironically named *"homepage"*?**

Comment: It must be the latter.  You should be able to tell by adding some nonsense like `style="background-color:penguin;"` to the template and them doing a "View source" on the homepage and searching for that text.

Comment: inline styling only applies to that one element. Maybe you have some other rule being applied to the rest. Use the developer tools in chrome or firebug in firefox to determine where the styles for each element are coming from.

Comment: @RichieHindle Oh your cheatsheet kinda tip is great. Thank you. It was the later.

Comment: @Elmer Thank you, where can I find the developer tools?

Comment: your theme is probably modular, i.e., broken up into small chunks or sections that can be re-used across various pages. your homepage template probably uses the same module that is used on the page you are trying to change. One way to target by page in a templating system is to add a class to the body tag that identifies the page. You can then use this class to target your div by page.

Comment: Dev tools on Firefox and Chrome is found by pressing F12 on Windows

Comment: F12 also works in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I Think that's impossible probably you forget changed you had done first in css file , you can try to change  color to GREEN or another color to verify the CSS applied .

the solution for you problem to change some DIV's style use a second class with `!important`

for exemple in CSS :

```
.bg-chnage {

background : pink !important ;

}
```

and in your html :

```
<div id= "content" class="row bg-chnage "   > </div>
```

this will solve your problem .

Comment: The use of `!important` in CSS rules should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Yes use a lot of " !important " no practice ,  but I think we have the situation here ?  because he want to modifies just some codes for now ?

Comment: I don't know what !important is. Secondly I am using the `background-color` property as a test, but ultimately I'll be changing some `CSS` of this one particular `div`, that's why I am testing with the `background-color` does.

Comment: Can I use the `!important` keyword in the inline style as well?

Comment: @Zarah you can check this [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) article on the use of `!important`

Comment: Yes you can use it with any CSS property this keyword force this style to applied